# VB Net: How to call this Public Shared Function?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Can anybody help me with a couple of doubts?
How can I call this Public Shared Function from a button? and how can I show "result" (list of files) in a datagridview?
Thanks.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports System.Net



Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       '?
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function retrieveAllFiles(service As DriveService) As List(Of File)
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    Secrets.ClientId = "CLIENT ID"
    Secrets.ClientSecret = "CLIENT SECRET"

    Dim scope = New List(Of String)
    scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.Drive)
    Dim credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, scope, "USER", CancellationToken.None).Result()
    Dim initializer = New BaseClientService.Initializer
    initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
    initializer.ApplicationName = "APPLICATION NAME"
    Dim service = New DriveService(initializer)
    Dim request As FilesResource.ListRequest = service.Files.List()
    Dim result As New List(Of File)()
    Dim request As FilesResource.ListRequest = service.Files.List()
    Do
        Try
            Dim files As FileList = request.Execute()
            result.AddRange(files.Items)
            request.PageToken = files.NextPageToken
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message)
            request.PageToken = Nothing
        End Try
    Loop While Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken)
    Return result
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: show how you are using it, **that** is the relevant code

Comment: yourclassname.retrieveAllFiles(...)

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the same class, you can just call it by name, same as a non-shared function:

```
lst = retrieveAllFiles(service)
```

If it's in another class, you need to prefix it with class name:

```
lst = className.retrieveAllFiles(service)
```

Official reference:

- [Shared Members in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Arvo and Neolisk but when I call it like in your examples it says: service its not declared. How can I declare it. Sorry if its too simple, Im new with apis.

Comment: @user3822492: You probably should know better what DriveService object is, but something like `Dim service As New DriveService(parameter1, parameter2, etc.)`.

Comment: For uploads I just need to do some changes from "Dim request As FilesResource.ListRequest = service.Files.List()" to down and works fine.

Comment: @user3822492: Ok, I'll put it in other words. Is your problem resolved? Was my answer helpful? If yes to both, please accept. Thanks in advance.